Is Ubuntu an operating system?
I realize Ubuntu is built atop Linux source, including the GUI perspective using X, etc.
It is a lightly abstracted deviation of a standard Linux protocol GUI-based OS in that it doesn't natively differ from desktop Linux, such as how Android does without native X support implemented.
However, when referring to a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, should one refer to Ubuntu, the kernel software part and the originating source, or should one refer to Ubuntu, the software on top of Linux?
Because it is all confusing saying I have "Linux on my desktop" and "I have Ubuntu on my desktop", which can be essentially the same thing when you really consider it and break away the middleware.

In my opinion Linux is the kernel and Ubuntu is the operating system that is built using the Linux kernel, like all other Linux based OSes.

"[W]hen referring to a Linux distro, such as Ubuntu, should one refer to Ubuntu, the kernel software part and the originating source, or should one refer to Ubuntu, the software on top of Linux?"
When referring to a Linux distro, you should use the name of the distro.
"[I]t is all confusing saying I have "Linux on my desktop" and "I have Ubuntu on my desktop", which can be essentially the same thing when you really consider it and break away the middleware."
Effective communication is about the message received, not the message sent.
Call it whatever you like to be clear to your audience. If your audience is confused, then adjust your message.

Ubuntu an operating system? It's actually some entity's packaging of the basic Linux operating system with a whole lot of supporting things.  The original question also suggested a keyword "desktop".  That's a whole nother level of programs (modern term might be applications or apps) in addition to the Ubuntu package which has Linux at it's core.
Many people think ubuntu means the whole big picture however, that packaging comes in several subsets.  There is Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu Xubuntu and probably a whole lot more.  The desktop, which many people think of as the look-and-feel is actually a package (and related subpackages) on top of the basic ubuntu.  That look and feel of the primary ubuntu is gnome.  In my case, I use the Xubuntu version which uses XFCE4 to provide the look and feel of the desktop or user display environment.
To those who want the shortest answer (Windows, Apple, or something else), probably calling it Linux or Ubuntu would be work.  If you are writting a future question in this portion of Stack Exchange and your question is in anyway related to your desktop environment, it would be gnome, xfce etc.
